# 301 .htaccess strange behavior and exact matches

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've recently moved my blog and I'm just 301 redirecting a few pages. Trouble is I've found an annoying issue.

There are two links -

```
hxxp://www.domain.com/category/post.html
hxxp://www.domain.com/category/
```

I'd like to 301 both to a new domain and so wrote the following...

```
Redirect 301 hxxp://www.domain.com/category/post.html  hxxp://new.domain.com/category/post.html
```

That worked fine, then I did the category...

```
Redirect 301 hxxp://www.domain.com/category/ hxxp://new.domain.com/
```

Since the category structure is different I just wanted to 301 it to the homepage.

Trouble is, this redirect is affecting the first redirect, presumably because it's very similar to the first.

Any ideas how I can only 301 redirect exact matches?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the order in which you have given the rules.

Comment: Just remove `hxxp://www.domain.com` part and you are good: the OLD_URL part of `Redirect` directive should start with slash and should not contain domain name: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Redirect always redirect directory to directory

You can use ModRewrite

```
RewriteRule ^category/$ http://newdomain/ [R=301]
```

to redirect 1 page

```
RewriteRule ^category/.*$ http://newdomain/ [R=301]
```

to redirect all directory to 1 (main) page

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of matching you want to use mod_rewrite, the swiss army knife of URL rewriting ;-)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /category/post.html$ http://new.domain/post.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule /category.* http://new.domain/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: If placed in `.htaccess` this will not work -- URL pattern will NOT contain leading slash `/`. But will work fine if placed in config or virtual host context.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the RedirectMatch directive ([see docs here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)) that allows you to use a regular expression to match the url to be redirected. With this, you can add a $ symbol at the end to specify the end of the string:

```
RedirectMatch 301 hxxp://www.domain.com/category/post.html$ hxxp://new.domain.com/category/post.html
RedirectMatch 301 hxxp://www.domain.com/category/$ hxxp://new.domain.com/
```

This way, the redirect will only affect exact matches.

Alternatively, you could use the RewriteRule directive ([docs here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)) like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /category/post.html$  hxxp://new.domain.com/category/post.html [ R=301, L ]
RewriteRule /category/$  hxxp://new.domain.com/ [ R=301, L ]
```

The L flag (stands for Last) forces Apache to stop processing other Rewrite directives

Comment: If placed in `.htaccess` these RewriteRules will not work -- URL pattern will NOT contain leading slash `/`. But will work fine if placed in config or virtual host context.

Comment: I didn't know of this difference. You could then replace the leading `/` with a `^`